# Can this question be migrated, if the reason to close it was specifically being off topic and more of an engineering question?

Tags: support, migration

I have this question:

[Why are turbines more effective than propellers on airplanes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/574123/why-are-turbines-more-effective-than-propellers-on-airplanes)

Unfortunately, it has been closed. The reason is off topic and specifically belonging rather to Engineering.

I do not have the ability or privileges to self-migrate it, and as I understand the rules and guidelines, since the question does have an upvoted answer, it cannot be migrated in the usual way.

The only way for me to do this would be to upload it newly to Engineering, and delete it from this site. The problem with this is that it then would not have the already upvoted question on it (as I understand the answerer is present on Engineering too).

I believe this is a technical problem, and the question has to be either:

1. reopened on physics
2. or migrated to Enginerring

It does not make sense in my understanding to leave this on Physics and keep it closed with the reason to belong to Engineering. If the reason for closing it is specifically to be off topic and needs to be migrated, then technically not allowing it to be migrated does not make sense.

Anyone please advise or I am asking the moderators sincerely to migrate it.

Answer (score 2):

Except for a migration to Math SE, all migrations require the intervention of a moderator. If you are confident this question (or any other, as long as it is not $\ge$ 60 days old) is off-topic here but on-topic on another site, feel free to flag it for moderator attention with the flag button under the post. It is also possible to just post the question on another site without going through the migration process.

Note that just because something is closed here as an engineering question does not necessarily mean it is [on-topic at Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Even if it is, it may be better received elsewhere, such as [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please make sure a question is on-topic on the other site before flagging it for a moderator.

Comment: Thank you I did.

Answer (score 1):

Chris has given you good general guidance.  But in the interest of transparency: I declined your migration-request flag, partly because I'm not convinced the question would be on-topic at Engineering, and partly because you have already accepted an answer.  Your question's upvoted answer should protect it from [the roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

My advice is that if you have remaining related questions, you ask them on a more appropriate site, with links back to the partly-satisfactory answer that you already have here.